# Possible to write ordered json data into file? How to do it using Python?

Tags: python, json, http, get, ordereddictionary

By using HTTP GET request, I write exchange rates from http://openexchangerates.org/api/ into a file, which looks like this:

```
{"timestamp": 1436266865, "rates": {"EUR": 0.911228, "JPY": 122.5463, "AUD": 1.346118}}
{"rates": {"AUD": 1.345790, "EUR": 0.912256, "JPY": 122.4428}, "timestamp": 1436270462}
{"timestamp": 1436277661, "rates": {"JPY": 122.4789, "AUD": 1.348871, "EUR": 0.914330}}
```

Is it possible to write this file somehow with the data ordered?

1. I'd like "timestamp" to precede "rates".
2. I'd like the currencies to be ordered (either alphabetically using their 3-character codes "AUD", "EUR", "JPY"  or  by using my
   own custom order, say, I want "JPY","EUR","AUD").

With the alphabetical ordering, the desired result would be:

```
{"timestamp": 1436266865, "rates": {"AUD": 1.346118, "EUR": 0.911228, "JPY": 122.5463}}
{"timestamp": 1436270462, "rates": {"AUD": 1.345790, "EUR": 0.912256, "JPY": 122.4428}}
{"timestamp": 1436277661, "rates": {"AUD": 1.348871, "EUR": 0.914330, "JPY": 122.4789}}
```

My Python script, which fetches this data is:

```
import json, requests

BASE_URL = 'http://openexchangerates.org/api/'
APP_ID = 'my_secret_app_id_here'

def fetch_fx():
    uri = 'latest.json'
    fx_all = (requests.get(BASE_URL + uri + '?app_id=' + APP_ID)).json()
    rates = {k:fx_all[k] for k in ('timestamp', 'rates')}
    with open('/datafiles/fx.json', 'a') as f:
        f.writelines(json.dumps(rates) + '\n')

a = fetch_fx()
```

If what I want is not possible due to HTTP-GET or JSON design, I could probably achieve the ordering by using Python's [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in my script.

Comment: Have you tried `sort_keys=True`?

Comment: Good point, thanks.  This nicely sorts the currencies alphabetically.  But it also puts "timestamp" at the end, not at the beginning of each line, as I want.